# How to sort a data frame by row in R and split into muliple data frames?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, split

Suppose I have a data frame :

```
       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6

 Row1    1     0     20     4     8    23
 Row2    0     1      3    61     2     1
 Row3    1     1      2     4     3    54
```

I want to sort this data frame into multiple data frames since I want the column information too.

```
       Col6  Col3  Col5  Col4  Col1  Col2
 Row1    23    20     8     4     1     0

       Col4  Col3  Col5  Col2  Col6  Col1
 Row2    61     3     2     1     1     0

       Col6  Col4  Col5  Col3  Col1  Col2
 Row3    54     4     3     2     1     1
```

Comment: Read about apply and order.

Comment: There is an issue with  apply(df,1,order) as variables names will not be coherent. If keeping variables names of the order is required, the only way in indeed to split into separate data.frames, ie manage via a list. One way to do that can be: `listdf=split(df,1:nrow(df)` and then use `lapply` to reorder each data.frame.

Comment: Looking at your questions, it seems that you have never accepted an answer to your questions. Please make it a habit to accept the answer you consider most useful by clicking the check mark that appears next to it. This will help other visitors by showing them that an answer helped. And it will help the answerer and yourself by giving both reputation points. You can also have a look at the [tour], to learn how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I was using a stylish style and the upvote and check marks weren't visible. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comment by [Eric Lecoutre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558861/eric-lecoutre), you could use `lapply()` in this situation. There are different ways to do this and I give you two examples.

The sorting is done in both examples with the function `order()`. How it works is easiest understood with an example:

```
x <- c(3, 4, 1, 2)
x[order(x)]
## [1] 1 2 3 4
x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)]
## [1] 4 3 2 1
```

So, `order()` does not return an ordered vector but rather the indices that can be used to order the vector.

Now to the solutions of your actual problem. You could apply over row indices as follows:

```
lapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) df[row, order(df[row, ], decreasing = TRUE)])
```

Or you could split the data frame in a list of data frame with a single row and apply over that list:

```
lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), function(row) row[, order(row, decreasing = TRUE)])
```

Comment: Thank you for specifying splitting into a list of data frames. In my original original data frame, I have referenced the rows by some names. However, when I tried your code, those row names seem to have gotten lost in the list. I tried this code - `q3<-lapply(split(q, 1:nrow(q)), function(row) row[, order(row, decreasing = TRUE)],function(x){ row.names(x)<-as.character(rownames(x)[]); x})`  , however I get this error - `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (function (x) 
{
    row.names(x) <- as.character(rownames(x)[])
    x
})`

Comment: I get data frames that have both, row and column names, so it seems I can not reproduce your issue. The error message is due to the fact that you can not pass two functions to `lapply(). Look at `?lapply` to understand better how it works.